# How to automatically index acronyms under a different index entry?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, acronyms, makeidx

I would like to use scribal abbreviations of the works of Aristotle (e. g. NE or EE), but the author (Aristotle), who may not specifically named or cited, should automatically appear in the Index of Persons every time I use the acronym (like citations if one uses the indexing=cite option in biblatex). So the individual acronyms of the works of Aristotle should appear under the index entry "Aristotle", but other acronyms should not appear in the index.

So here is a MWE, perhaps somebody has an idea - would be great!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeindex[columns=2,title=Titelregister]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=personenregister,title=Index of Persons]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=sachregister,title=Index of Subjects]
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[personenregister]}
{\namepartfamily}
{\namepartgiven}
{\namepartprefix}
{\namepartsuffix}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Scribal Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[SIP]
 \acro{SIP}{\textit{Super Important Problem}} 
  \acro{EE}{\textit{Eudemian Ethics}}. 
  \acro{NE}{\textit{Nicomachean Ethics}}. 
\end{acronym}

\newpage

Aristoteles\index[personenregister]{Aristotle} was a student of Plato\index[personenregister]{Plato}

\newpage

In the Eudemian Ethics, there is written: \frqq this and that\flqq\ (\acs{EE}, II.1 1219a19-28).
%should appear in the index of persons under the entry Aristotle

\newpage

I call this problem the \textit{Super Important Problem} (\acs{SIP})
%should not appear in the index of persons

\newpage 

In the Nicomachean Ethics, there is written: \frqq that and this\flqq\ (\acs{NE}, I.9, 1099b32-1100a1).
%should appear in the index of persons under the entry Aristotle

\printindex[personenregister]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too hard with `acro` instead of `acronym` (if you don't mind switching packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreport}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2,name=personenregister,title=Index of Persons]

\acsetup{
  use-id-as-short ,
  format/long = \itshape ,
  index/use = true ,
  index/cmd = \index[personenregister]
}

\DeclareAcronym{SIP}{long=Super Important Problem,no-index}
\DeclareAcronym{EE}{long=Eudemian Ethics,index=Aristotle} 
\DeclareAcronym{NE}{long=Nicomachean Ethics,index=Aristotle}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Scribal Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading = none]

\newpage

Aristoteles\index[personenregister]{Aristotle} was a student of Plato\index[personenregister]{Plato}

\newpage

In the Eudemian Ethics, there is written: >>this and that<< (\acs{EE}, II.1 1219a19-28).
%should appear in the index of persons under the entry Aristotle

\newpage

I call this problem the \ac{SIP}
%should not appear in the index of persons

\newpage 

In the Nicomachean Ethics, there is written: >>that and this<< (\acs{NE}, I.9, 1099b32-1100a1).
%should appear in the index of persons under the entry Aristotle

\printindex[personenregister]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, interesting package :)